# Regular expression to validate first two characters only in SQL

Tags: sql-server, regex

I have a requirement to check that a value does not contain the letters D,F,I,Q,U or V in the first TWO characters only

Within SQL, I have tried

`LIKE '[DFIQUV][DFIQUV]%'`

with no luck. It is not validating if the second character is one of the listed characters (works for the first one)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the check for each of the first two characters:

```
WHERE (COL LIKE '[DFIQUV]%' OR COL LIKE '_[DFIQUV]%')
```

Comment: thanks @Bohemian - I didn't need the NOT but checking the two characters seperately worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need something like this:

```
create table #a(col varchar(10))

insert #a(col)
select 'ABC' union all
select 'EFG' union all
select 'DFI' union all
select 'QUV'

--unnecessary rows
select * from #a where col not like '[DFIQUV][DFIQUV]%' --1st version (means 'and' condition between two letters)
select * from #a where col not like '[DFIQUV]%' or col like '_[DFIQUV]%' --correct version (manually 'or' condition)

--necessary rows
select * from #a where col not like '[DFIQUV]%' and col not like '_[DFIQUV]%'
```